# Run multiple function using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

i am new to web programming. i am trying to connect database using jsp with odbc. i have already written a java code for this. now i need to run on Tomcat server. so i choose JSP to do this job.But this is showing me void type not allowed here and erors. how to run this code using jsp. what are my mistakes. please help me to solve in this.
now this is my code

```
 <%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.*" %>
 <%@page import="java.util.logging.Level"%>
 <%@page import="java.util.logging.Logger"%>

 <%! 
 int i=0,j=0,k=0;
 Connection conn=null;
 Connection connection=null;
 static int count=0;

    String Cname[]=null;
    String Title[]=null;
    Statement stmt1=null;
    ResultSet NumOfRows=null;
    Statement stmt2=null;
    ResultSet SpreadsheetValues=null;
    Statement stmt3=null;
    ResultSet rs3=null;
    int RowCount;
         //this static function required to connect excel database
  static
  {
    try {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("Exception in connecting to DB"+e.getMessage());
    }
  }

   // connect Sql database
    void ConnectSqlDB() {
  try{
  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ServerDB","sa","sqladmin");
  System.out.println("MSSQL connected " +"<br>");
  }catch(Exception e){
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.out.println("Exception in connecting to DB"+e.getMessage());
  }
  }
  void ConnectExcelDB() throws SQLException{
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:spreadsheetdb","","");
 }
  void getRowcount() throws SQLException{
     stmt1=conn.createStatement();

     String Qs1="select count(*) from [Sheet1$]";
     NumOfRows=stmt1.executeQuery(Qs1);
     while(NumOfRows.next()){
     Rowcount=NumOfRows.getInt(1);
     }
     NumOfRows.close();
    }
     void getExcelValues() throws SQLException{
        stmt2=conn.createStatement();
        String Qs2="select * from [Sheet1$]";
        SpreadsheetValues=stmt2.executeQuery(Qs2);

        Cname=new String[Rowcount];
        Title=new String[Rowcount];
        while(SpreadsheetValues.next()){

    // Assigning Spread sheet values to String array

               Cname[j]=SpreadsheetValues.getString("Cname");
               Title[j]=SpreadsheetValues.getString("Title");
               j++;
         }
     }
          SpreadsheetValues.close();
          stmt2.close();
          conn.close();
          SpreadsheetValues=null;
          stmt2=null;
          conn=null;
 }
   %>
      <%=ConnectSqlDB()%>
      <%=ConnectExcelDB()%>
      <%=getRowcount()%>
      <%=getExcelValues()%>
```

Comment: Is '"select count(*) from [Sheet1$]";'  a valid SQL query? I guess you need to use bind variables there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `<%= %>` (Expression) to invoke void methods and you should have to avoid Java code in JSP (read [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)).

```
<%
  ConnectSqlDB();
  ConnectExcelDB();
  getRowcount();
  getExcelValues();
%>

<p>Total Records : <%=RowCount%>
<p>Array element at 0 index <%=name[0]%>

<%
 for(String v:name)
 {
   out.println("<br/>" + v);
 }
%>
```

Comment: @user1074824 - You may write value from variable using expression <%=var_or_expression%>

Comment: how do u print the result for arrays. assume i assigned "name" values to name[j], how to print this?

Answer (score 1):

When you are using a method in a JSP Expression, then your method should return a value. I see all of your methods have a return type of `void` i.e. returning nothing. Change your methods to return appropriate value.

**NOTE**

I understand that you are currently learning JSP etc but keep in mind that writing contorl/application logic in a view technology like JSP is a bad practice. Try reading the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).